# How to make a transition delay itself after page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
 <style type="text/css">
 .demo{
 background-color:red;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 }
 </style>
 <script>

function animateDuration(){
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
setTimeout(function(){x[0]},1000);
}    

</script>
</head>
<body onload="animateDuration();">
<div class="demo animated pulse">Just some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get my transition into effect after 1 second of page load. I am trying to do this by `javascript` DOM as I am learning DOM.

Comment: there's no transition in the code you posted - css, you'd use `transition-delay`

Comment: @jaromandax the transition is in `link`. Im using animate.css transitions

Comment: You're already doing it with the timeout, but `x[0]` does nothing, it just references an element ?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have included the animate.css file in the `link` tag

Comment: @Explosion, don't just tell people that your CSS is in another file, we don't know what goes on in there. Do post it into the CSS part of your snippet. Thanks

Comment: `I have included the animate.css file` - so? that doesn't show its **CONTENT**

Comment: @Mark its a css plugin. If you want, I could post the entire plugin if you want but it would just ruin time and space.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do animations, try using css before javascript.

Because you haven't included the animate.css file, and you haven't told us anything about where you got it, then I have to guess. I would add the following css:

```
.animated {
  -o-transition-delay: 1s;      /* Early Opera */
  -moz-transition-delay: 1s;    /* Early Firefox */
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* Early Safari or Chrome */
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

It should add to or overwrite the setting in the `animated` class.  Perhaps you instead need to change the `.animated` class above to `.pulse` in the css code above. Worst case scenario, use `transition-delay: 1s !important;` to be sure to overwrite the included css file, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I do know how to work my code in `css`. The reason I'm not touching my `css` is because my `.animated` class is universal which would jeopardize my other animations. So I wanted to know the solution using` javascript` strictly.

Comment: You're not adding that into your animate.css file, but into you HTML file. You could also add a fourth class to that is named '.delay' and then add the css code above.

Comment: Yes but the main reason to post this question was to get the answer in `javascript` not css.

Answer (score 0):

transition work after 1000 milliseconds

```
    <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
 <style type="text/css">
 .demo{
 background-color:red;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 transition:1s;
 }

 .pulse{
 background-color:blue;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 transition:1s;
 }


 </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="divid" class="demo">Just some text</div>

<script>
function animateDuration(){
document.getElementById('divid').className = "pulse";
}    
setTimeout(animateDuration,1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to make a transition work after 1000 milliseconds and that transition is from the file `css/animate.css` named class `.pulse`. I do not want to change my width. This answer is completely wrong.

Comment: that was just an example for delay the transition from ajax method()

Comment: updated my code may be this will fit on your requirement

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `setInterval` method of jquery. After making your documnet ready
`var interval = setInterval(function(){
 all your animate  css animations here }, 3000);`
 added jQuery... reffer to this link :https://jsbin.com/wucesoniya/edit?html,js,output

Comment: And even clear that interval by calling this function inside that  ```function myStop() {
    clearInterval(interval);```
}

Comment: You have used `setInterval` which I do not want to use as it repeats itself but I have still used it and  doesn't seem to work. I have also tried the `setTimeout` and again, no luck.

Comment: it repeats itself but you need to clear the interval and just refer to first comment it will clear the interval

Comment: shouldn't I use `setTimeout` as a better option then? The transition doesn't even start so stopping the `setInterval` has no meaning for me, yet.

Comment: after adding all your animations code in that interval just add there ```clearInterval(interval);``` It will just run once on your document load

Comment: I was just telling you a way...Then there may be any other thing which you are making wrong

Comment: can you make a bin for this on jsbin and provide me the link

Comment: just make a bin for that

Comment: I have added jQuery and the solved your issue: https://jsbin.com/wucesoniya/edit?html,js,output